# Implementing nextval(); sequence in Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

How can I implement the `nextval();` function from PostgreSQL to my ID generator in my Laravel project?

I've tried the suggestion from ChatGPT but it does not work, I also searched the documentation about `nextval` but cant still get it to work in my project.

This is my function that generates the ID, the rule of my id generation is that it will scan the Student ID and id column of the `StudentModel` and `PersonModel` before generating an unassigned id, then the id will start with the prefix of 20 and must only be a 7 digit long. I have no problem generating ID numbers, but I want to implement the `nextval()` in my function.

```php
Route::get('/check-student-id', function() {
    $prefix = "20";
    $lastId = max(StudentModel::max('Student ID'), PersonModel::max('id'));
    $suffix = str_pad(($lastId % 100000) + 1, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $newId = $prefix . $suffix;
    $existingIds = array_merge(
        StudentModel::pluck('Student ID')->toArray(),
        PersonModel::pluck('id')->toArray()
    );

    while (in_array($newId, $existingIds)) {
        $suffix = str_pad(($suffix % 100000) + 1, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $newId = $prefix . $suffix;
    }

    return $newId;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextval` is used to obtain the next value of a SEQUENCE. What you're asking doesn't have anything to do with that. You just want to give a default value to your id field.

This can be achieved by updating the field when a model is created

```php
class YourModel extends Model
{
    public static function booted()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            ... logic here
            $model->id = $newId;
        });
    }
}
```

This is limited to only working when Eloquent is used to persist the data.

If you want the table to get this value automatically no matter how you persist the data, then you'll need to implement that logic in the database

Comment: oh, so my understanding about nextval is wrong the whole time, thanks for clarifying that out!